# How set "Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem" to NO full screen in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm newbie in Sencha and when I use Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem Launches view that I want to link but I do full screen, without the two bars up and down, how to tell me not to display it full screen? Thank you!

My code:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',  
    text: 'Show my other view',
    cls:'butview',
        listeners: {
        tap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
             Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem( {xtype:'myotherview'} );
             // Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem( 'app.views.myotherview' );
        }
    }
}
```

Image (I can not post images because my reputation is still low, the share from google drive)

![show] https://googledrive.com/host/0BwIaci1aJaoTbHB0SmxwX0hJalk/full%20screen..JPG
![as should the load][2] https://googledrive.com/host/0BwIaci1aJaoTbHB0SmxwX0hJalk/normal.jpg

Thankss

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A mockup picture, sketch would definitely help to identify the needed components and logic.

Comment: I can not post images because my reputation is still low, the share from google drive, 

as should show
https://googledrive.com/host/0BwIaci1aJaoTbHB0SmxwX0hJalk/normal.jpg

how show now
https://googledrive.com/host/0BwIaci1aJaoTbHB0SmxwX0hJalk/full%20screen..JPG 

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change content between title bar and buttons bar use
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel

Declare all views inside tabpanel.
To switch to another view use

```
/reference to tabpanel component/.setActiveItem(2)
```

2 is number of view